# List of ANSI C and C99 literal prefixes and suffixes

Tags: c, c99, literals, ansi-c

Where could I find a list of literal prefixes and suffixes for ANSI C and C99? I am looking for a list that contains only those defined in the standards (i.e. excluding compiler-defined prefixes/suffixes).


Examples of what I am talking about:

```
1L
999u
123456789LLU
0xABCDLL
12.55lf
678.1235932E-5

L"Hello, world!"
u8"stuff"
```

Comment: You could look in the standards. :)

Comment: here's a good site for integers: https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Literals/Integer#C  other types are there too

Answer (score 2):

See the formal grammar in Annex A of the C standard. The official standard is not freely available but here's a link to Annex A in the last draft version of C11, converted to html:

http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#A.1

Comment: Is there a reason why the offician standard is not freely available?

Comment: @MeikVtune: Because ISO charges money for it. (No, that money doesn't go to the volunteers who work on it.)